# Heroku deploying old version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am fairly new to rails. I originally deployed a rails app on Heroku. I decided then to delete that app from the heroku website and then created a new heroku app using the same original file on my computer. I changed a few styles, but otherwise it's the same code. Whenever I do a git push heroku master now, it updates the new app with the old version. I am practically ripping my hair out. I've done

```
git remote -v
```

and it seems to be sending my code to the new source. But it's not! It keeps giving me the display from the older version. It seems to be pulling from a different source than what I am pushing to. Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you probably have forgotten to push the latest commit to your repo?

Comment: try restarting the heroku server?  `heroku restart` in the terminal in your app's directory

Comment: I tried heroku restart and it still has the old design. I checked 'git status' and there's nothing to push.

Comment: I actually just tried to create another new app and the same thing is happening. It will only give me the original design from earlier in the day. Somehow, when I switched the app in heroku, the database that I'm currently pushing to seems to have been disconnected from wherever horuku is getting the design. Although I've done git remote -v, and it seems to be the right spot. I am very confused.

Comment: It turned out I had ran rake assets:precompile before making those changes. I ran rake assets:precompile again to include them, then committed and pushed to Heroku. It then incorporated my changes.

Comment: Are you certain that your new apps are actually pushing to heroku? Can you show the terminal output of what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget commit your changes or they aren't in master branch. Use this commands for diagnosis:

```
git status
git log heroku/master..master
git branch -a
```

Comment: I did git status and there's nothing to push it says.